# Using the index in ng-options

Tags: angularjs

I have a select that shows the elements of an array. I want to bind this select to the index of the element. I have this code

```
var choices = [
  'One',
  'Two',
  'Three'
];

<select
  ng-model="model.choice"
  ng-options="idx as choice for (idx, choice) in choices">
</select>
```

That works but if the array has more than 10 elements the order of the options in the select does not match the order of the elements in the array. It seems that angular does a sort of the "value" attribute of the options which holds the index of the element in the array without leading zeros so the sort goes "1", "10", "2", "3", ...

How can I workaround this and have the options enumerated in the same order they appear in the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we look at the documentation of the Angular select directive found here:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select

We see that the value for ngOptions has two specific sets of syntaxes.  One for the data being an array and one for it being an object.  In your example, you have used a pattern for object data sources when your data is an array.

Specifically:

```
ng-options="idx as choice for (idx, choice) in choices"
```

is only applicable when the variable called `choices` is an object.